# how to map *& in SWIG?

Tags: c++, swig

I have the below code in c++, `p` is a person array.

```cpp
void GetPersonArrayRef(Person*& p)
{
    Person* plist = p;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (plist[i].name) << std::endl;
    }
    Person p0, p1, p2;
    p0.name = "0name";
    p1.name = "1name";
    p2.name = "2name";
    Person* a = new Person[3]{ p0,p1,p2 };
    p = a;
}
```

the generated c# type is `SWIGTYPE_p_p_Person` of `Person*&`.

I want to call the method like this `GetPersonArrayRef(ref Person[] list)` in c# code. Can someone help?

If can't do like above, can give me any other tips?

Comment: This can’t possibly work: Swig has no means to recover the length of the array from a simple C++ pointer, which it would need in order to construct a C# array. You may want to pass a reference to a vector instead.

Comment: I don't think this is a good interface design. If you know the sizes somehow it could work, but still be non intuitive. Passing a std::vector or std::list by non const reference is a better option, but still somewhat weird.